# Convert binary executable to dynamic library

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, macos

I have an existing iOS binary that was linked with Xcode "Mach-O Type" of "Executable" that I want to use as a dynamic library. If I change the "Mach-O Type" to "Dynamic Library" then it works as intended, but I do not have access to the source code.

How can I convert an existing iOS binary into a dynamic library?

Comment: You can't.  A dynamic library, among other things, has a list of exported functions and other symbols.  How would you create that list from an executable?

Comment: Is it still possible without creating this list? Basically I'd like to make the executable appear to be a dynamic library.

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to wrap an executable in a dynamic library?

Comment: On iOS, you can't launch external executables, even if they are bundled with your code.  There's no way to write a library to use an external executable to do the work.  I suggest you open a new question describing the functionality you need and asking for specific suggestions on how to implement it (libraries/frameworks/etc.).

Comment: Thanks @Avi, posted a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900104/embed-mach-o-binary-in-mach-o-dynamic-library